# std::string& vs boost::string_ref

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

Does it matter anymore if I use `boost::string_ref` over `std::string&` ? I mean, is it really more efficient to use `boost::string_ref` over the std version when you are processing strings ? I don't really get the explanation offered here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/utility/doc/html/string_ref.html . What really confuses me is the fact that `std::string` is also a handle class that only points to the allocated memory, and since c++11, with move semantics the copy operations noted in the article above are not going to happen. So, which one is more efficient ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have never used it be it seems to me that its purpose is to provide an interface similar to `std::string` but without having to allocate a string for manipulation. Take the example given `extract_part()`: it is given a hard-coded C array `"ABCDEFG"`, but because the initial function takes a `std::string` an allocation takes place (`std::string` will have its own version of `"ABCDEFG"`). Using `string_ref`, no allocation occurs, it uses the reference to the initial `"ABCDEFG"`. The constraint is that the string is read-only.

Comment: But what's the difference between a function handling parameter of type "const boost::string_ref" and "const std::string&"?

Comment: I think it's better to read @sehe 's answer that describes that calling substring on string_ref returns another string_ref instead of new std::string.

Answer (score 6):

The use case for `string_ref` (or `string_view` in recent Boost and C++17) is for **substring references**.

The case where

- the source string happens to be `std::string`
- **and** the full length of a source string is referenced

is a (a-typical) special case, where it does indeed resemble `std::string const&`.

Note **also** that operations on `string_ref` (like `sref.substring(...)`) automatically return more `string_ref` objects, instead of allocating a new `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

This answer uses the new name `string_view` to mean the same as `string_ref`.

> What really confuses me is the fact that `std::string` is also a handle class that only points to the allocated memory

A `string` allocates, owns, and manages its own memory. A `string_view` is a handle to some memory that was already allocated. The memory is managed by some other mechanism, unrelated to the `string_view`.

If you already have some text data, for example in a `char` array, then the additional memory allocation involved in constructing a `string` might be redundant. A `string_view` could be more efficient because it would allow you to operate directly on the original data in the `char` array. However, it would not permit the data to be modified; `string_view` allows no non-`const` access, because it doesn't own the data it refers to.

> and since c++11, with move semantics the copy operations noted in the article above are not going to happen.

You can only move from an object that is ready to be discarded. Copying still serves a purpose and is necessary in many cases.

The example in the article constructs two new `string`s (not copies) and also constructs two copies of existing `string`s. In C++98 the copies could already be elided by RVO without move semantics, so they're not a big deal. By using `string_view` it avoids constructing the two new `string`s. Move semantics are irrelevant here.

In the call to `extract_part("ABCDEFG")` a `string_view` is constructed which refers to the `char` array represented by the string literal. Constructing a `string` here would have involved a memory allocation and a copy of the `char` array.

In the call to `bar.substr(2,3)` a `string_view` is constructed which refers to parts of the data already referred to by the first `string_view`. Using a `string` here would have involved another memory allocation and copy of part of the data.

> So, which one is more efficient?

This is a bit like asking if a hammer is more efficient than a screwdriver. They serve different purposes, so it depends what it is you're trying to accomplish.

You need to be careful when using `string_view` that the memory it refers to remains valid throughout its lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

If you stick to `std::string` it does not matter, but `boost::string_ref` also supports `const char*`. That is, do you intend to call your string processing function `foo` with `std::string` only?

```
void foo(const std::string&);

foo("won't work"); // no support for `const char*`
```

Since `boost::string_ref` is constructable from `const char*`, it is more flexible since it works with both `const char*` and `std::string`.

The proposal [N3442](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3442.html) might be helpful.

Comment: It will work, but will incur temporary `std::string` object creation (as `std::string::string(const char*)` constructor isn't `explicit`)

Comment: @milleniumbug please add your comment to the post by editing it and remove your comment, I will remove this comment as well.

Comment: @milleniumbug I will then delete it. I want to improve StackOverflow and better answers/deleted invalid answers helps in doing so.

Answer (score 0):

**In short**: The main benefit of `std::string_view` over `const std::string&` is that you can pass both `const char*` and `std::string` objects without doing a copy. As others have said, it also allows you to pass substrings without copying, although (in my experience) this is somewhat less often important.

Consider the following (silly) function (yes I know you could just call `s.at(2)`):

```
char getThird(std::string s)
{
    if (s.size() < 3) throw std::runtime_error("String too short");
    return s[2];
}
```

This function works, but the string is passed by value. This means the whole length of the string is copied even though we don't look at all of it, and it also (often) incurs a dynamic memory allocation. Doing this in a tight loop can be very expensive. One solution to this is to pass the string by const reference instead:

```
char getThird(const std::string& s);
```

This works a lot better if you have a `std::string` variable and you pass it as a parameter to `getThird`. But now there's a problem: what if you have a null-terminated `const char*` string? When you call this function, a temporary `std::string` will get constructed, so you still get still get the copy and dynamic memory allocation.

Here's another attempt:

```
char getThird(const char* s)
{
    if (std::strlen(s) < 3) throw std::runtime_error("String too short");
    return s[2];
}
```

This will obviously now work fine for `const char*` variables. It will also work for `std::string` variables, but calling it is a little awkward: `getThird(myStr.c_str())`. What's more, `std::string` supports embedded null characters, and `getThird` will misinterpret the string as ended at the first of these. At worst this could cause a security vulnerability - imagine if the function were called `checkStringForBadHacks`!

Another problem is simply that it's annoying to write a function in terms of old null-terminated strings instead of `std::string` objects with their handy methods. Did you notice, for example, that this function looks at the whole length of the string even though only the first few characters are important? It's hidden in `std::strlen`, which iterates over all characters looking for the null terminator. We could replace that with a manual check that the first three characters aren't null, but you can see this is a lot less convenient than the other versions.

Step in `std::string_view` (or `boost::string_view`, previously known as `boost::string_ref`):

```
char getThird(std::string_view s)
{
    if (s.size() < 3) throw std::runtime_error("String too short");
    return s[2];
}
```

This gives you the nice methods you expect from a proper string class, like `.size()`, and it works in both the situations discussed above, plus another:

- It works with `std::string` objects, which can be implicitly be converted to `std::string_view` objects.
- It works with `const char*` null-terminated strings, which can also be implicitly be converted to `std::string_view` objects.

  - This does have the potential disadvantage that constructing the `std::string_view` requires iterating over the whole string to find the length, even if the function that uses it never needs it (as is the case here). However, if a caller is using a `const char*` as a parameter to several functions (or one function in a loop) that take `std::string_view` objects it could always manually construct that object beforehand. This could even give a performance increase, because if that function(s) do need the length then it is precomputed once and reused.
- As other answers have mentioned, it also avoids a copy when you only want to pass a substring. For example, this is very useful in parsing. But `std::string_view` is justified even without this feature.

It's worth noting that there is a case where the original function signature, taking a `std::string` by value, may actually be better than a `std::string_view`. That's where you were going to make a copy of the string anyway, for example to store in some other variable or to return from the function. Imagine this function:

```
std::string changeThird(std::string s, char c)
{
    if (s.size() < 3) throw std::runtime_error("String too short");
    s[2] = c;
    return s;
}

// vs.

std::string changeThird(std::string_view s, char c)
{
    if (s.size() < 3) throw std::runtime_error("String too short");
    std::string result = s;
    result[2] = c;
    return result;
}
```

Note that both of these involve exactly one copy: In the first case this is done implicitly when the parameter `s` is constructed from whatever is passed in (including if it is another `std::string`). In the second case we do it explicitly when we create `result`. But the return statement does not do a copy, because uses move semantics (as if we had done `std::move(result)`), or more likely uses the [return value optimisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision#Return_value_optimization).

The reason the first version can be better is that it is actually possible for it to perform zero copies, if the caller *moves* the argument:

```
std::string something = getMyString();
std::string other = changeThird(std::move(something), "x");
```

In this case, the first `changeThird` does not involve any copy at all, whereas the second one does.

Comment: I'm afraid that 'raise' is no keyword in C++ - it looks pythonic :-). Can you explain it or fix it (just use `throw`)?

Comment: Oops, you're right - I always forget that when switching between C++ and Python! Thanks for pointing it out :-)